# firebaseConfig.default.auth promise rejection error

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to signup user with facebook but i am seeing very rigid error and it seems there is no solved help out there so i am asking again 
thats my code

```
async function signInWithFacebook() {
    // const appId = Expo.Constants.manifest.extra.facebook.appId;
    Facebook.initializeAsync(appid)
    const permissions = ['public_profile'];  // Permissions required, consult Facebook docs

    const {
      type,
      token,
    } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
      {permissions} 
    );
    if(type == "success"){
        const credential = initFirebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
        initFirebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
  }
```

i am using appid in strings but i have not added it here hope you understand that.
and the error is this
[image]

this is my firebase config file code

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/auth"
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxx"
};
  // Initialize Firebase
const initFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default initFirebase
```

variable values are hidden because of privacy .i worked with firestore and that worked but i am seeing issue with auth with facebook .

> i am using react native , firebase , expo and not firebase sdk

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to register a Facebook App for Login with Facebook using Firebase. You can use the below code with Firebase Facebook Authentication enabled in the console.

```
export const loginWithFacebook = (accessToken) => {
  const credential = initFirebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken);
  return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
    signInWithCredential(credential).then(response => {
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: hello , you are talking about Facebook.initializeAsync()
this part of code ? i dont want to initialize it ?

Comment: @samairali For firebase login, you need to be using your application on http or https protocol. Are you using fbsdk to login? If using fbsdk I will change my answer accordingly